# Python3 Trying to execute sql query with dynamic column names

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am using `sqlite3` and I am trying to dynamically return specific columns from  database using SELECT query, problem is I keep getting the column names back instead of the actual rows. Here is an example code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_name.db')
c = conn.cursor()

query = 'SELECT ?, ? FROM devices'
columns = ('name','network-id')
c.execute(query, columns)

print(c.fetchall())
```

This is the result I get:

```
[('name', 'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id'), ('name',    'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id'), ('name', 'network_id')]
```

It is very annoying, I am only trying to get back specific columns from my results, but I get the column names instead. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: in line 6 of the code it is actually 'network_id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use SQL parameters for table or column names, only for literal values.

Your query is the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT 'name', 'network-id' from devices
```

Just put the column names directly into the query:

```
columns = ('name','network-id')
query = 'SELECT %s from devices' % ','.join(columns)
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I had no idea SQL parameters can only be used for literal values.

Answer (score 0):

Use columns **name, network-id** in the `SELECT` query itself as follows:

```
query = 'SELECT name, network-id FROM devices'
```

? is used to relpace value in the query for example

```
query = 'SELECT name, network-id FROM devices where name = ?'
columns = ('my-name')
c.execute(query, columns)
```